# Play 2.4 migration:JavascriptReverseRoute is not a member of object play.core.Router error

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.4, typesafe-activator

Iam new to scala play framework, I have used this JavascriptRoute.scala file for AJAX calling in play 2.3.9 and it was working fine.

```
package controllers

import play.api.Routes
import play.api.mvc.Action
import play.api.mvc.Controller
import play.api.mvc.EssentialAction
import play.core.Router.JavascriptReverseRoute
import play.core.Router._
import routes.javascript.Application.index
import routes.javascript.Organizations.ajaxCallOrgStatus
//import routes.javascript.Users.ajaxCallForDomain
import routes.javascript.Users.domainMap

object JavascriptRoute extends Controller {

  /* Application related JavascriptReverse Route will goes here */
  val appRoutes: List[JavascriptReverseRoute] = List(index,ajaxCallOrgStatus,domainMap)

  /* All JavascriptReverse Route will combine here */
  val javascriptRouters = appRoutes

  /**
   * This is used to generate JavascriptReverseRoute for all provided actions
   *
   * @return
   */
  def javascriptRoutes: EssentialAction = Action { implicit request =>
    import routes.javascript._
    Ok(Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(javascriptRouters: _*)).as("text/javascript")
  }
}
```

When I migrated to play 2.4 framework it shows the following errors

**[error] D:\my-app\app\controllers\JavascriptRoute.scala:7: value JavascriptReverseRoute is not a member of object play.core.Router
[error] import play.core.Router.JavascriptReverseRoute
[error]        ^
[error] D:\my-app\app\controllers\JavascriptRoute.scala:17: not found: type JavascriptReverseRoute
[error]   val appRoutes: List[JavascriptReverseRoute] = List(index,ajaxCallOrgStatus,domainMap)**

I have tried to fix the import statements for play 2.4.x but I couldn't find a alternate for this import play.core.Router.JavascriptReverseRoute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been moved under `play.api.routing`:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.3/api/scala/index.html#play.api.routing.JavaScriptReverseRoute

Comment: I have tried this import but also facing the same issue play.api.routing

Comment: This import exists, are you sure? Look at this note: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.3/api/scala/index.html#play.core.Router$

Comment: After adding that import we are facing this issue "[error] D:\myapp\JavascriptRoute.scala:30: value javascriptRouter is not a member of object router.Routes
[error]     Ok(Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(javascriptRouters: _*)).as("text/javascript")"

Comment: That's on another line and most likely due to a wrong import again. Everything that relates to route is now under the package mentioned above. (Check `play.api.routing.Router`)

Comment: Also, the syntax slightly changed I think, it might be a good idea to read doc at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting to make sure your code is up to date.